# I am using protected route , who is logged in only see this route otherwise it goes to the login page , i have emplement this component but its gives

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom, mern

i am using react.js , i have a component of protected route but when i used in react.js it gives me an error
[ProtectedRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

[here is my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxgl8.png)

help me out of this
[here is my app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlbf3.png)

in console it gives me error
[ProtectedRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>